# Question about the deduction of Hamiltonian of Schwinger model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian, dirac-equation

In Sidney Coleman's paper [More about massive schwinger model](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(76)90280-3) ([PDF](https://sci-hub.ru/https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(76)90280-3)). Discuss about some property of massive (1+1)D QED model, In page 5 of this paper, Coleman derive the following Hamiltonian of Schwinger model:

[image]

where $F_{01}$ denotes the 0,1 component of EM tensor, in (1+1)D, $F_{01}$ is just simply the electrostatic field $E_x$ and $F$ is an external background field (to be consider as a constant).

$F_{01}$ defined as: $F_{01}=E_x=e\partial^{-1}_1j_0+F $
(in Page 4, equation 2.5)

So my question is, how to derive the Hamiltonian (2.10) by "trivial integration by parts"? After I tried many times, I get the first and third term, but I still can't derive the second term (term with the absolute value one) in the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
H_{\rm interaction}=\frac 12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^2 (\partial_x^{-1} j_0(x))^2 dx\\ =\frac 12 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx dx' \delta(x-x') (\partial_x^{-1} j_0(x)) (\partial_{x'}^{-1} j_0(x'))
$$
Now $\delta(x-x') = \partial^2_x  \left(\frac 12 |x-x'|\right)$, so  integration by parts to take the derivatives off the potental and on to the currents gives
$$
H_{\rm interaction}=-\frac 1 4 e^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx dx' |x-x'|j_0(x)j_0(x').
$$
I did not look at the $xFj_0$ term.